# IBM WAS createEJBStubs

Tags: ejb, websphere

I want to use the `createEJBStubs` command, which is described [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Frejb_3stubscmd.html).

But when I apply it to my .ear file deployed on the server I get the following exception:

> CNTR9258E: Error: Unexpected exception "error in opening zip file" occurred.

Has anyone come across this problem? What can be done to create the stubs successfully?

Here's what I get using the `-verbose` option:

```
CNTR9258E: Error: Unexpected exception "error in opening zip file" occurred.
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:203)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:132)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:97)
    at com.ibm.ws.deploy.tools.CreateEJBStubsCommand.main(CreateEJBStubsCommand.java:279)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:183)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:90)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformActivator$1.run(PlatformActivator.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:339)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:94)
Command Failed
```

Comment: You probably found a product defect, so I would recommend opening a PMR with IBM.  If you use the `-verbose` or `-trace` options, you might be able to guess at a suitable workaround.

Comment: can you open your ear file with other programs like Winzip or 7zip, to make sure you don't actually have a corrupt ear file?

Comment: to kurtcebe
thank you, yes, I've opened it with 7zip, and it's absolutely OK.to bkail:
thank you, I'll try and ask IBM, too.

Comment: @gisly If you post the output of those two options (particularly any unusual errors), someone here might be able to help.

Comment: @gisly It looks like something is wrong opening the zip file.  Are you able to list the contents of the ear with "WAS_HOME/java/bin/jar tf app.ear"?

Answer (score 1):

I use this syntax:

```
call <WAS's Path>\createEJBStubs.bat <file-name.jar> -cp <project's dependecies>;
```

P.S.: Important all dependencies stay in the same folder to be run the command line.